# UpdatePanel asynchronous postback not calling TextChanged event of TextBox

Tags: asp.net

Why isn't the UpdatePanel asynchronous postback calling the TextChanged event of the TextBox, in the code shown below?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ConPhameNet" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="Labelabc1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox1" EventName="TextChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The TextBox does not have an `OnTextChanged` event handler attached to it (at least, not in markup). Do you attach the event handler in code behind?

Comment: Yes,, TextChanged is attached to Textbox, it is not shown here because Page property AutoEventWireup="false".

Comment: Can you show in the question how you attach the event handler in code-behind?

Comment: This is my event handler, textbox TexChanged event can call this if i don't use update panel but when i am using update panel it is not called.  Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Me.Labelabc1.Text = "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
    End Sub

Comment: When I test your code, it works perfectly: I change the text in `TextBox1`, I tab out of the TextBox, and I see the new text in the Label.